# Magento 2 : Path not writable

Tags: magento2, bug

I'm new to Magento 2 so I still don't have the best experience to debug it.

I recently encountered this issue :

The path `"_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US:///var/www/html/magento/pub/static/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/"` is not writable

This directly triggers on the home page. I have no idea how to fix it.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated as I'm still trying to figure out how this new CMS is working.

Comment: Did you get this error message after running setup:upgrade? Which web server are you using Apache2 or ngnix?

Answer (score 7):

The solution was only related to permissions issues.

I recommend to anyone facing these kind of issues to run these commands :

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

source: devdocs.magento.com

Comment: does anyone know if this is a good answer? Im scared to try it !

Comment: @styzzz it works. I have a variation of this which I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it's permission issues. I have used these commands without any problems:

```
cd <Magento root dir>
chown -R :<group> .
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
chmod +x bin/magento
```

It's basically the same as WecK0's answer.

For easy use, I made a function and put it in ~/.bashrc:

```
function fixperm() {
# used for local server
if [ "$PWD" = "<Magento root dir>" ]; then
    echo "### CHOWN-ing all to :<group>"
    chown -R :<group> .
    echo "### CHMOD-ing all directories to 770"
    find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
    echo "### CHMOD-ing all files to 660"
    find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
    echo "### CHMOD-ing bin/magento to executable"
    chmod +x bin/magento
    exit 1
else
    echo "You can only run this command in webroot!"
    exit 1
fi
}
```

which can be run in terminal by typing `fixperm`.

Answer (score 0):

Running this chain of commands on SSL fixed this problem:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 pub var app/etc
```

Answer (score 0):

For development purpose, one should do following things to debug error fastly.

- Set `developer` mode and remove `#` from `.htaccess` in root directory from line no 5.

  > ## SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
- To display errors . Paste followoing lines in `index.php`

  > ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  >   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  >   error_reporting(E_ALL);
- And apply file permissions suggested by Weck0 as per devdocs.

  ```
  cd your_Magento_install_dir
  find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
  find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
  chown -R : .
  chmod u+x bin/magento
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As per your error message what i can understand is that you `pub` folder is not having enough permission so that Magento 2 can write into it. Running the below command can help you.

```
chmod -R 777 pub
```

**Note:** Note change 777 to whatever security setup you have on your server. 777 will give full read and write permission to the pub folder.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2.3 I have tried this code to pass the readiness check
first I have gone to root directory with root user

`sudo chmod -R 777 pub`